# undefined method `errors' in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

Hi I am beginner to ruby on rails and I am developing small blog application using this ref
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

I am facing following problem  here .

```
 <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
<% if @post.errors.any? %> // Error showing undefined errors method
<div id="errorExplanation">
  <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
    this post from being saved:</h2>
```

I am beginner to this environment. How to solve this problem. Need help. Thank you.

Comment: Iam guessing that @post is nil. Please post the code with generates @ post

Comment: `<% @post ||= Post.new %>` Please add this line into your views

Comment: @rajarshi thank you for solution. But can you please explain how it works.

Comment: yes it is just instantiate the Post object....now the funda is ||= it will check if the post is exists or not like in edit post already exists for new in your case Post is not instantiate so the error throw  .....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your controller:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

and in your View

```
 <%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
   <div id="errorExplanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
         this post from being saved:</h2>
```

Yes, you simply have to instantiate the Post object....now in your case, Post is not instantiated so that error is thrown. You also should know that errors is defined as an instance method not as a class method. Hence it will be called on a specific instance.

You can find more information on active model errors using the following link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html

Comment: It's a very bad suggestion to add that in the view. This is typically something that should be done in the controller. You're teaching a beginner the wrong way.

Comment: But, what if Post is not a model and has only a controller and a view?

Answer (score 3):

In your controller:

```
def new
  @post = Post.new
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="errorExplanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
          this post from being saved:</h2>
```

Comment: @nilkash Please see Rajarshi answer it is more perfect

Comment: No, your answer is better. It's very bad to suggest doing that in the view. @badal